# Can I use the uWSGI to product my application if I use the eventlet.wsgi in the Django project's `wsgi.py`?

Tags: python, uwsgi

Can I use the uWSGI if I use the eventlet in the Django project's `wsgi.py`?

in my project's `wsgi.py`:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "AProject.settings")


from socketio import Middleware
from xxx.website_chat.views import sio
django_app = get_wsgi_application()
application = Middleware(sio, django_app)

import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)
```

there I use the `eventlet.wsgi.server()` do my application, whether when I distribute my project, I still need the uWSGI as the webserver?

---

**EDIT-1**

I mean, if I still need the uWSGI as the webserver if I use the bellow code:

```
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)
```

---

**EDIT-2**

I use the `eventlet.wsgi.server` in my project `wsgi.py`:

`import eventlet.wsgi
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)`

Now I want to distribute my project.

When I use `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini`:

there will get bellow error:

```
mapped 208320 bytes (203 KB) for 4 cores
*** Operational MODE: threaded ***
django.setup()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myProject/wsgi.py", line 30, in <module>
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)
  File "/Users/lll/Desktop/myProject/Project/myProject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 78, in listen
    sock.bind(addr)
OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 11413)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 11418, cores: 4)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 11419)
```

and I use `lsof -i:8000` ferret out the `uwsgi` is using the `8000` port.

```
$ lsof -i:8000
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
uwsgi   11413  ldl    4u  IPv4 0x9bf2de3fe3ee0367      0t0  TCP *:irdmi (LISTEN)
uwsgi   11419  ldl    4u  IPv4 0x9bf2de3fe3ee0367      0t0  TCP *:irdmi (LISTEN)
```

so the eventlet.wsgi can not listen the address: `eventlet.listen(('', 8000))`

Whether when I distribute my project, I do not need the uWSGI ?  use the eventlet.wsgi.server directly?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You still need something to run the WSGI app, don't you?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Do you mean I still need the uwsgi to run my application?